# Randomly subset a large network with given type of nodes and weights

Tags: python-2.7, networkx

I have a small network with two types of nodes and given wights. I would like to randomly sample similar network from a large network.

I have a smaller network built with NetworkX in python2.7 with two types of nodes and specific weights. I have a another huge network/Graph. I would like to randomly sample the huge network maintaining the connectivity of smaller network (types of nodes and edges). It can be stated as randomly sampling a network.

My initial data looks like this:

```
Connections                                       Weight
chr22,43266979,43269138:chr22,43400294,43400976    15
chr22,43409329,43433936:chr22,43290595,43292626    15
chr22,43409329,43433936:chr22,43277663,43278699    17
chr22,43266979,43269138:chr22,43399124,43400293    15
chr22,43409329,43433936:chr22,43399124,43400293    1
chr22,43409329,43433936:chr22,43278700,43281477    16
chr22,43409329,43433936:chr22,43262566,43266683    18
chr22,43409329,43433936:chr22,43281478,43285053    16
chr22,43266979,43269138:chr22,43350529,43356580    9
chr22,43409329,43433936:chr22,43400294,43400976    1
chr22,43433937,43434687:chr22,43277663,43278699    18
chr22,43266979,43269138:chr22,43437394,43454270    21
```

I have a dict with the type of nodes:

```
node_type = {"chr22,43266979,43269138":"TypeA","chr22,43433937,43434687":"TypeA","chr22,43409329,43433936":"TypeA"}
```

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as pat

G = nx.Graph()

with open("data.txt") as f:
    header=f.readline()
    for line in f:
        conn, weight = line.strip().split()
        node1,node2=conn.split(":")
        G.add_edge(node1,node2, weight=int(weight))


for node in G.nodes:
    G.node[node]['category'] = node_type.get(node,"TypeB")

color_map = {'TypeA':'blue', 'TypeB':'red'}
nx.draw(G, node_size=100,node_color=[color_map[G.node[node]['category']] for node in G])
pat.show()
```

The small network looks like this [1]

[image: "small network"]

Now I have a very large network and I would like to select a subgraph that has same number of type of nodes and the connectivity (and wights) as my smaller network. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I assume the subgraph needs to be connected, right? That might be obvious, but I'm only a little familiar with graph algorithms.

Comment: The subgraph needs to have similar connections with similar weights.

Comment: What connectivity would you consider to be "similar"? Surely, if the connectivity and weights are exactly the same, you are not actually randomly sampling.